# Revive NotificationListernerService on Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, android-service, xiaomi, notification-listener

I have been testing my NotificationListenerService related app on my Xiaomi device , and found that as soon as the app is closed , the service is also killed or it goes inactive, the workaround I found was to use togglecomponent method like at this URL: https://gist.github.com/xinghui/b2ddd8cffe55c4b62f5d8846d5545bf9.

but with this example I found multiple clients created each time the component is toggled that are all listening to notifications , and thus this results in multiplied actions of the task in intended by the listener Service class.
How do I restrict number of clients created to one, 
or is there a way to revive old client with toggle component ? 
or any other alternative to revive NotificationListenerService component
thanks.

```
  private void toggleNotificationListenerService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "toggleNotificationListenerService() called");
        ComponentName thisComponent = new ComponentName(this, /*getClass()*/ NotificationCollectorService.class);
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(thisComponent, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(thisComponent, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
```

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Comment: I corrected it @user1241241

Comment: okay,,, good move

Comment: Hi everyone, I want to revive the NotificationListenerService, 
its working perfectly fine, when I have just installed the app through ADB, but once the app is killed or closed, the Xiaomi devices stop listening to the notification service, and thus I want to revive the listening service.